# Unity ScriptableObject is missing on mobile build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, debugging

I have a `MonoBehaviour` class that has a property referencing another class which is `ScriptableObject`.

I've created several prefabs of my first class and created several `ScriptableObjects` of my second class, I've referenced them in the first class respectively.

In the editor everything works fine, except sometimes my so are shown in the Inspector as Missing Script and in property reference as `NameOfSO ()`, don't know what causing this, but again, Play in the Editor is working just fine.

If build my game for Android and connect to the Debug, to see what's going on, I can clearly see, that's `ScriptableObject` reference is `null`. Why? Don't know, came here to ask a question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, turns out this was happening because of the weird thing with namings.
Allow me to explain, when I first created a class from `ScriptableObject` I used, lets say, `MyClas` name, I've created several instances of that class, but then I saw the error in the name of the class, I've changed it to the `MyClass` but only in the file itself, not the actual `.cs` file, so, this was happening. All I had to do is to ensure that my class and my file names are the same, delete old instances of `ScriptableObject` and create new ones from scratch and... Voila!
Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. In a word, just make sure your file name is the same with your class name.